# Rebekah's rash/brash/hasty willingness to bear curses become reality for her in Genesis 27:46

Tags: hebrew-bible, marriage

> Genesis 26:34-35 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>    34 When Esau was
>   forty years old he [ae]married Judith the daughter of Beeri the
>   Hittite, and Basemath the daughter of Elon the Hittite; 35 and they
>   [af]brought grief to Isaac and Rebekah.

Could Rebekah's rash/brash/hasty overemotional willingness to bear curses for her second son, Jacob, chance to get blessings in Genesis 27:13 be seen as actually becoming a reality in Genesis 27:46? (Genesis 27:46 seems to indicate that Esau's wives, who seemed to be Canaanites, did Not get along with Isaac and Rebekah, and caused them much trouble and distress)

> Genesis 27:8-14 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>   8 Now therefore, my
>   son, listen to [a]me [b]as I command you. 9 Go now to the flock and
>   [c]bring me two choice [d]young goats from there, that I may prepare
>   them as a savory dish for your father, such as he loves. 10 Then you
>   shall bring it to your father, that he may eat, so that he may bless
>   you before his death.” 11 Jacob [e]answered his mother Rebekah,
>   “Behold, Esau my brother is a hairy man and I am a smooth man. 12
>   Perhaps my father will feel me, then I will be as a [f]deceiver in his
>   sight, and I will bring upon myself a curse and not a blessing.” **13
>   But his mother said to him, “Your curse be on me, my son; only obey my
>   voice, and go, get them for me.”** 14 So he went and got them, and
>   brought them to his mother; and his mother made savory food such as
>   his father loved.

---

> Genesis 27:46 New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>   46 Rebekah said to
>   Isaac, “I am tired of [d]living because of the daughters of Heth; if
>   Jacob takes a wife from the daughters of Heth, like these, from the
>   daughters of the land, what good will my life be to me?”

Could Rebekah's rash/brash/hasty overemotional willingness to bear curses for her second son, Jacob, chance to get blessings in Genesis 27:13 be seen as actually becoming a reality in Genesis 27:46?  (Genesis 27:46 seems to indicate that Esau's wives, who seemed to be Canaanites, did Not get along with Isaac and Rebekah, and caused them much trouble and distress)

Basically, when Rebekah (in an emotional state) tells Jacob let the curses fall on me in Genesis 27:13, does Not her request for the curses to fall on her actually become true when the **daughters of Heth( i.e., Esau's wives)** become troublesome to her later in life?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Basically, when Rebekah (in an emotional state) tells Jacob let the curses fall on me in Genesis 27:13, does Not her request for the curses to fall on her actually become true when the daughters of Heth( i.e., Esau's wives) become troublesome to her later in life?

Comment: But Jacob did _not_ take a wife of the daughters of Heth. Jacob married Rachel. It was Esau who married a Hittite.And Jacob did _not_ bring a curse upon himself (from his father). Isaac blessed Jacob.

Comment: Yes, I did emphasize **daughters of Heth( i.e., Esau's wives) **

Answer (score 1):

Esau's Hittite wives had always been a problem. However, after Rebekah became aware of Esau's threat to kill Jacob (Gen. 27:41-42), she used the excuse of not wanting Jacob to marry local women to get permission from Isaac to send Jacob away to find a wife. Isaac blessed this plan (Gen. 28:1).

> Gen. 27:41 - And Esau hated Jacob because of the blessing wherewith
>   his father blessed him: and Esau said in his heart, The days of
>   mourning for my father are at hand; then will I slay my brother Jacob.
>
> Gen. 27:42 - And these words of Esau her elder son were told to
>   Rebekah: and she sent and called Jacob her younger son, and said unto
>   him, Behold, thy brother Esau, as touching thee, doth comfort himself,
>   purposing to kill thee.
>
> Gen. 27:46 - And Rebekah said to Isaac, I am weary of my life because
>   of the daughters of Heth: if Jacob take a wife of the daughters of
>   Heth, such as these which are of the daughters of the land, what good
>   shall my life do me?
>
> Gen. 28:1 -  And Isaac called Jacob, and blessed him, and charged him,
>   and said unto him, Thou shalt not take a wife of the daughters of
>   Canaan.

No curses followed Jacob's nor Rebekah's deceptions. Rebekah was told by the Lord in Gen. 25:23 that the older would serve the younger. It appears that both Jacob (obtaining birthright) and Rebekah (obtaining blessing for Jacob) were 'inspired' acts to bring about the original prophecy.

> Gen. 25:23 - And the Lord said unto her, Two nations are in thy womb,
>   and two manner of people shall be separated from thy bowels; and the
>   one people shall be stronger than the other people; and the elder
>   shall serve the younger.

All verses KJV.